# How to extract own classes with Tailwindcss to separate file

Tags: tailwind-css

I have app.css file like

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
    
@import url('features/login/login.css');
    
@tailwind utilities;
```

In login.css code like

```css
.login-button {
  @apply w-full flex justify-center border border-transparent;
}
        
body {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

The rule for body works, but for the login-button does not

How I can create own css class based on tailwind classe in our css files?

Thanks

**update**: added html file (it Aurelia-framework template)
Original template

```html
<template>
  <span class="login-button-wrapper">
   <button type="submit" class="login-button">
    Sign in
   </button>
  </span>
</template>
```

Fixed template

```html
<template>
<require from="./login.css"></require>
<span class="login-button-wrapper">
 <button type="submit" class="login-button">
    Sign in
 </button>
</span>
</template>
```

Comment: Please share the html code where you have used the .login-button class

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I find solution: need manual add css file to template. But I think if I link app.css to root module of my application, all custom classes will be work. Maybe its js-framework feature/issue

Comment: All you have to do is change the file name to `login.scss` and then run `php artisan dev` to compile it back to .css

Answer (score 2):

You can write your style under your tailwind assets

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

.login-button {
  @apply w-full flex justify-center border border-transparent;
}
        
body {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

like this, if prefer using the file you can also  use the
directive before that you need to make sure you have installed

```
npm install postcss-import
    

 @import url("path");
     or
  @import "path";
```

You need to check if the path is correct and rebuild your app again this will work

Answer (score 2):

Best guide I found so far

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

// Base
@layer base {
  @import "base/variables";
  @import "base/elements";
}
...
```

https://bloggie.io/@kinopyo/organize-your-css-in-the-tailwind-style-with-layer-directive

Answer (score 1):

If you use PostCSS, you just need to change the import line to this

`@import "features/login/login.css";`.

Also, make sure that you have the `postcss-import` plugin connected.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors/#build-time-imports.